# Why specifying a generic argument as interface is not an error with a class constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a generic method like this one:

```
static void Foo<T>() where T : class
{

}
```

I could call it by specifying an interface type, for example `ICollection<int>`

```
Foo<ICollection<int>>();
```

Now assume I have a struct that implements `ICollection<int>`:

```
struct Bar : ICollection<int>
```

I can't specify it explicitly as the type argument, but if I have a variable of type `ICollection<int>` that has the underlying type `Bar`, and change my generic method to take an argument of type `T`, I can do:

```
static void Foo<T>(T arg) where T : class
{

}

ICollection<int> bar = new Bar();
Foo <ICollection<int>>(bar);
```

As you can see it completely ignores the generic constraint. So my question is why specifying an interface as a type argument is allowed when we have a `class` constraint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "class" constraint is really a "reference type" constraint - it doesn't *specifically* mean classes. (It works with delegate types too.) From [the MSDN page on generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Now for your example:

> As you can see it completely avoids the generic constraint.

No it doesn't. It uses `ICollection<int>` as the type argument, and that *is* a reference type. Note tha the value you're passing into the method *is* a reference, due to boxing.

Comment: hmm I guess I didn't consider the boxing factor. that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the  documentation

> where T : class  =>  The type argument must be a reference type; this
>   applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

[Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

`int` is a value type but `ICollection<int>` is not.

Comment: I know it is allowed, I'm asking why and doesn't it violates the class constraint... apperantely it does not.

Comment: @Selman22 Yes, Because ICollection<int> is a reference type, which is T in your case